# How to make color settings look the same in vim as in gvim

Tags: vim

When I put the following in .vimrc

colorscheme blue

It gives me a nice blue colorscheme in gvim.  However, when I use vim, it is light blue instead.  Is there a setting I can change so that gvim and vim look the same?  If not, then is there a way I can set it up so that my gvim settings do not interfere with my vim settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set your vim settings in the `.vimrc` file, and set the gvim settings in the `.gvimrc` settings file.

Just pick a different colorscheme in the `.gvimrc`...

Comment: Ok, that works.  I don't understand why in the gvim menu for editing startup settings it goes to the .vimrc file and not the .gvimrc file.

Comment: Because most of your startup settings will be in .vimrc. Only GUI specific settings belong in .gvimrc.

Answer (score 13):

As well as John's suggestion of using `.gvimrc`, there are a couple of other interesting alternatives:

If your command-line vim is compiled with `+gui` (`:echo has("gui")`)* and you have a 256 colour capable terminal, you can use the [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) plugin to convert the GUI colour scheme into a matching command line one.

If your command-line vim doesn't have `+gui`, you could try (I haven't used this one) the [guicolorscheme](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1809) plugin.  The guicolorscheme plugin parses the colour scheme file, so it isn't as robust as the CSApprox one (it almost certainly won't work with [my colour scheme](http://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/bandit-colour-scheme) for example.

There's a lot more information on both of those methods [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_GUI_color_settings_in_a_terminal) and [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim).

---

* Regarding has("gui"):

If you're not interested in `+gui`, stop reading now!

Personally, I'd recommend this as it simplifies things a bit - you get the opportunity to type `:gui` if you want to change from terminal to GUI and as you inevitably have `+X11` and `+xterm_clipboard` as well, you can copy to the X clipboards from console vim.  If your vim doesn't have `+gui`, the easiest way to fix it is to create a link in your personal `bin` directory to the GUI executable:

```
ln `which gvim` ~/bin/vim
```

GVim will quite happily work as a console vim if the executable name is `vim`.  A "default" build from the vim source with GUI enabled will create one executable (`vim`) and lots of links to that executable like `gvim`, `gview`, `view`, `vimdiff` etc.  Most Linux distributions seem to compile them separately though, in order to minimise requirements of the basic Vim (so you can use vim without installing X).  As such, I tend to recompile and install in /usr/local with the features I want as I always have X installed (it doesn't have to be running, just installed).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a modern terminal which support 88 or 256 colors(most of them do like gnome-terminal or roxterm(on linux) not sure about Mac or Windows) , you should check out this vim script CSApprox(http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390). This scripts make the color schemes made for gvim, work with terminal vim.